# unix script file not found when attempting to run ./autogen.sh

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to build **espeak-NG** https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/blob/master/docs/building.md on a laptop with **Windows 10** and currently trying to implement the prereq step of installing 'the pcaudiolib project checked out to src (as src/pcaudiolib).' - I cloned **pcaudiolib** https://github.com/espeak-ng/pcaudiolib to the src folder in espeak-ng and attempted to run `./autogen.sh` in WSL, resulting in the following:

```
root@DESKTOP-CLS8BP6:/mnt/c/users/lenovo/desktop/espeak-ng/src/pcaudiolib# ./autogen.sh
-bash: ./autogen.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I use `ls` to check the contents of the directory, `autogen.sh` is clearly there:

```
root@DESKTOP-CLS8BP6:/mnt/c/users/lenovo/desktop/espeak-ng/src/pcaudiolib# ls
AUTHORS  autogen.sh  CHANGELOG.md  configure.ac  COPYING  Makefile.am  README.md  src
```

What's going on?

Comment: Its saying that /bin/sh^M is not there. If there is a a /bin/sh, edit the authgen.sh to remove the ^Ms from it, which are carriage reyurns not expected in linux files - perhaps lime endings set wrong when you checked out the repo?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem like that's the case. when I check out authgen.sh, there is no ^M in the file, and  file -h /bin/sh tells me that I have a symbolic link to bash.

Comment: what are you using to view the file as its probaly hiding the fact that the carriage return is there. And it IS obviously there since it says: '/bin/sh^M'

Comment: I used Notepad, Notepad++, and vim

Comment: both will handle the fact it has the wrong newlines - In vim, run :set ff? to display the fileformat.

Comment: it returns `fileformat = dos`

Comment: yep - so has \r\n not \n line endings - which shows up as ^M

Comment: I removed all the newlines from authgen.sh using Notepad++ and i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it's apparent that you have a script with DOS-style CRLF line-endings that "confuse" Linux/WSL apps/shells/etc., since they expect Unix/Linux LF-only line-endings.

This might have been caused during the checkout.  You checked out the repo to your *Windows* desktop (`/mnt/c/users/lenovo/desktop/`), so I'm assuming you did it with Windows git.

Typically, you'll want to stick with the Linux tools (`git`, your editor, etc.) when working with code in WSL.

Attempting to clean up every potentially impacted file manually is probably not the best option.

Try this:

Start in your WSL distribution.  I'm assuming this is Ubuntu, but it probably doesn't matter unless you need additional packages.

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng.git
cd espeak-ng
./autogen.sh
```

That should avoid the mixture of Linux/Windows-DOS style line-endings.

Comment: I still get the following error when I do this:
```root@DESKTOP-CLS8BP6:~/src/espeak-ng/src/pcaudiolib# ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: 13: aclocal: not found```

Comment: Hmm - Do you have all dependencies installed per the instructions?  I just ran through it myself, and it completed without issue on Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2.  Also just to confirm, you are using WSL2, right?  Double-check with `wsl -l -v` (from PowerShell).